# Hadoop AWS doesn't show output on the screen

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive

When I run the code below in the AWS,

```
SELECT year, MAX(temperature)
FROM records
WHERE temperature != 9999
AND (quality = 0 OR quality = 1 OR quality = 4 OR quality = 5 OR quality = 9)
GROUP BY year;
```

I get "OK" from AWS EMR as shown in the first image …

[image]

… but I can't see the expected result/output

```
1949  111
1950  22
```

like the one in this second picture:

[image]

**The code I tried:**

```
hive>
> SELECT year, MAX(temperature)
> FROM records
> WHERE temperature != 9999
> AND (quality = 0 OR quality = 1 OR quality = 4 OR quality = 5 OR quality = 9)
> GROUP BY year;

Query ID = hadoop_20180302235859_3409fe28-465e-4857-9c10-243bcaafe819
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Status: Running (Executing on YARN cluster with App id application_1520032089791_0005)

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1 .......... container     SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
Reducer 2 ...... container     SUCCEEDED      1          1        0        0       0       0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 02/02  [==========================>>] 100%  ELAPSED TIME: 5.03 s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK
Time taken: 6.488 seconds
```

Comment: Please reformat your question using the [Markdown made available](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)  to you as a poster.

Comment: Please take time to well format your questions, otherwise no one might help you (as I did this time as an edit).

Answer (score 0):

It is telling you that no rows of data match your WHERE statements.

You should debug the queries to figure out why you aren't getting the expected result.

For example, the data in the tables might be different. Try to view the data with:

```
select * from records limit 10
```

Then drill-down further:

```
select * from records where temperature != 9999 limit 10
```

Check what values are given for `quality` and whether they would match your WHERE statement.

Rather than asking why it *didn't* work, aim to prove that the data is there and show that it *should* work.